# Posting an image from a file instead to Facebook?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook

How would I go about posting an image from a file instead to Facebook? This works fine:

```
SLComposeViewController *controllerSLC = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
[controllerSLC setInitialText:@" iPhone app"];
[controllerSLC addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com"]];

[controllerSLC addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"]];
```

However I'm trying to send an image from:

```
 self.imageView.image = [self.photo objectForKey:photoPictureKey];
```

Comment: You can get image, UIImage *image = [self.photo objectForKey:photoPictureKey];

Comment: What is the data type of self.photo, and what is returned by [self.photo objectForKey:photoPictureKey] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this mate** (iOS6),

*send your image to this method,*

Make Sure you add Social.framework and `#import <Social/Social.h>`

```
-(void) uploadToFaceBook:(UIImage *) image{


    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]){

        SLComposeViewController *fbController =[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler __block completionHandler=
        ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){

            [fbController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

            switch(result){
                case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                default:
                {
                    NSLog(@"Cancelled.....");
                }
                    break;
                case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                {
                    NSLog(@"Posted....");
                    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sent" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                    [alert show];
                }
                    break;
            }};

        [fbController addImage:image];
        [fbController setInitialText:@" iPhone App"];
        [fbController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com"]];

        [fbController setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
        [self presentViewController:fbController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry"
                                                            message:@"You can't post on Facebook right now, make sure your device has an internet connection and you have at least one Facebook account setup"
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if this `[self.photo objectForKey:photoPictureKey]` code returns the path of the image you can use UIImage class method that is imageWithContentsOfFile:

```
UIImage *fbImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self.photo  objectForKey:photoPictureKey]];
```

Then check fbImage is it is not nil before adding it to the instance of the class SLComposeViewController

```
 if(fbImage!=nil){
  [controllerSLC addImage: image];
 }else{
  NSLog('image is nil'); 
 }
```

if this "[self.photo objectForKey:photoPictureKey]" code returns the a UIImage instance then do this:

```
 UIImage *fbImage = [self.photo objectForKey:photoPictureKey];
 if(fbImage!=nil){
  [controllerSLC addImage: fbImage];
 }else{
  NSLog('image is nil'); 
 }
```

you can also check if fbImage is null by:

```
if(fbImage!=nil && !([fbImage isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])){
    [controllerSLC addImage: fbImage];
```

}